# Android ADT - Eclipse | Dont changes R.java when editing or adding Ids in views / layout files

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My problem is above.

If i try to change a view object Id (for example a TextView) inside a Layout file, nothing happens inside the R.java file, so i can't appeal to my TextView inside an Activity.
I don't know what happend, because i did not changed anything in Eclipse or something.

I also tried this in a New Android Application Project and inside of this new Project i did not had this Problem.    Maybe i changed a setting inside my main project or something.

Do someone could give my a Tipp or have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse is buggy with R files. Try saving, then closing your android project, reopening, and cleaning your project. Make sure it's set to build automatically.

Comment: I fixed the problem, with cleaning the project.  There was an error in my project because i had drawable resources with the same name / id (a button png image and for this button a xml file with the same name)  so Eclipse could not overwrite the R.java file!  Thanks for the hint! :)